# Remove 'printer added' notifications from GNOME 3

Tags: gnome, printing, 17.04, gnome-shell, notify-osd

I've just upgraded to Ubuntu 17.04, using the GNOME desktop. Suddenly, I've started seeing 'printer added' notifications as OSD popups - approximately every 2 minutes! It's really distracting.

Anyone have any idea how I can either stop them at source, or at the very least filter them out from the OSD notifications?

Comment: This is a problem for me as well in Ubuntu 17.10. I've reported a bug here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1725955

Comment: Never had the problem until 20.04, which is addressed by @jimsmith solution.

Comment: I have this problem in Ubuntu 20. It's annoying when I'm trying to use the computer as a slideshow server.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The problem that you're identifying appears identical to my case, which is, that upon OS restart, the system goes through an auto-discovery/auto-install process, and then politely notifies the user via a notification window (the OSD, or on-screen display). Yet then--periodically--this process seems to repeat itself for some as yet unknown reason.

Seems to me that somewhere in the new 17.04 driverless printer driver discovery logic, something is broken. The best I can tell is that the `colord` daemon is failing on a missing ICC file for the printer in question, which causes CUPS to want to "reinstall" the printer driver, and hence the repeating "printer installed" OSD message. Perhaps as a clue, when installing a "non-driverless" printer driver, the corresponding ICC is installed correctly.

In my own case, I've solved the problem by preventing CUPS from initiating this auto-everything process entirely. In this way, I install my printer(s) once, and never see a "printer added" OSD messages again.

The solution:

- Edit `/etc/cups/cups-browsed.conf`, changing the `BrowseRemoteProtocols CUPS
  dnssd` line to `BrowseRemoteProtocols none`
- Restart CUPS from Terminal
  `service cups restart`

Note that this assumes your printer(s) are on a LAN and not directly connected to your machine. If your printer is local (physically attached), you may want to edit `BrowseProtocols` instead (untested).

A restart of the CUPS service or machine reboot should resolve the "printer added" issue. Note that you'll need to manually add your printer(s), as the auto-discovery feature has now been disabled.

CUPS Reference: https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/5-cups-browsed.conf/

Rich

Comment: that sounds pretty plausible. My printer is indeed on the network. I'm not in the office today, but I'll try your suggestion next time I am. Thanks!

Comment: So that does definitely stop the OSD notifications, thanks @richbl. I do wonder if we should be reporting the root problem to a bug list somewhere, but I'm not actually sure where that somewhere should be!

Comment: For me the configuration file was `/etc/cups/cups-browsed.conf`

Comment: I do not care if the underlying process repeats.  I just want to avoid seeing the OSD messages.  Can those be disabled?

Comment: Does not work in 17.10.  I still get the notifications, and printer gets added, as a duplicate to a previously installed printer.

Comment: This stops remote printers from being installed. I just want the notification to stop.

Answer (score 25):

Follow these steps:

1. Go to **Settings**
2. Click **Notifications** on the **Sidebar**
3. Click **Printers** under **Applications**
4. **Turn Off** the Notification Toggle

Comment: This comment is God's work :)!

Comment: This makes me happy! @AnimeshKarnewar

Comment: I think this is a feature of later versions of Ubuntu, which does not require to edit the configuration file manually. Great!

Comment: Not all heroes wear capes. Thank you.

Comment: Here is the gsettings command that does the above: `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.notifications.application:/org/gnome/desktop/notifications/application/gnome-printers-panel/ enable false`

Answer (score 22):

So I thought I had found a solution (via FedoraForums actually):

```bsh
# Finding the schemas of interest:
$ gsettings list-schemas | grep -i notif

# Listing the values to target:
$ gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.print-notifications

# Changing the value:
$ gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.print-notifications active false
```

Source http://www.fedoraforum.org/forum/showthread.php?t=297053

Unfortunately, despite a brief pause, I'm still getting OSD notifications.

Comment: I can confirm that this seems to work in 16.04 LTS. Thanks

Comment: works like a charm on 17.10

Comment: Seems to do the trick on Debian 9. Probably a Gnome issue.

Comment: I like this answer because it demonstrates how to find the setting that needs to be changed, rather than just giving the fix. Plus you change the notification setting rather than turning off printer auto-detection altogether.

Comment: It doesn't help my Ubuntu 18.04 either.

Comment: It doesn't work on 20.04, for me at least.

Answer (score 10):

You need to stop [dns-sd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast_DNS) from constantly scanning in cups configuration:

Ubuntu 20.04:

edit `/etc/cups/cups-browsed.conf` and

change:

```
BrowseRemoteProtocols dnssd cups
```

to:

```
BrowseRemoteProtocols cups
```

Restart:

```
sudo systemctl restart cups
```

Comment: running ubuntu 20 - will give this a shot!

Comment: Work in 20.04..

Comment: I think this is working (Ubuntu 20 for me too).

Comment: `pkill gjs` to get rid of the current notifications so I can enjoy my video playlist on my kiosk mode VLC monitor.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with regular annoying printer added notifications. In my case, the root cause appeared to be the same as identified by richbl; missing colour profiles. I installed the missing colour profiles and the problem went away:

```bsh
sudo apt update
sudo apt install icc-profiles
sudo systemctl restart cups
```

Comment: Didn't work for me on Ubuntu 20.04 - I just got another random "Printer added" notification. 