# How do I disable network printer discovery in Ubuntu 17.10?

Tags: networking, printing, 17.10, notify-osd

I have an HP network printer on my local network.  I have installed HPLIP on my Ubuntu 17.10 laptop.  I keep getting OSD notifications of the same printer being added.  It is a duplicate printer instance that I do not want added to my system.

I have tried editing the cups config as directed here: [Ubuntu 17.04 - 'printer added' notifications under Gnome](https://askubuntu.com/questions/918462/ubuntu-17-04-printer-added-notifications-under-gnome)

That does not stop the OSD or the printer being added.

Comment: Which HP model printer do you have?

Comment: HP OfficeJet  Pro 8500A Plus

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to disable Bonjour on your printer.

Assuming the web interface for the HP 8500 is similar to the HP 8740, do the following:

1. In your web browser, go to your printer's setting page.

   `https://nnn.nnn.nnn.nnn/`

   Replace `nnn.nnn.nnn.nnn` with the IP address of your printer.
   (For local addresses, it is always a good idea to put the "`/`" at the end of the address).

   If you get a warning, "Your connection is not private", then click "Advanced" and select the "Proceed to ..." link.  (This is for Chrome, so the message on other web browsers may differ slightly).

   You will be taken to the printer's web configuration page.
2. Click on <kbd>Network</kbd>
3. Click <kbd>+ Advanced Settings</kbd> to expand it
4. Click <kbd>Bonjour</kbd>
5. Select the <kbd>Disable Bonjour</kbd> radio button
6. Click the <kbd>Apply</kbd> button
7. The *duplicate network detected* printer should disappear from your Ubuntu system.  If you manually setup the printer (using `hplip`), that version of the printer will still be available on your system.

[image: Disable Bonjour on an HP printer using the web interface]

Comment: Thanks.     "7. The network detected printer should disappear from your Ubuntu system."  Just to clarify, I don't want the printer to completely disappear from my system, just the duplicate copy?

Comment: Great!  Please do me a favor and accept the answer by clicking on the check-mark next to the answer.  (I'll also update step 7 to make it clear that the duplicate printer disappears).

Answer (score 0):

Try going to the CUPS control panel in your browser, `https://localhost:631`

Administration > Manage Printers > "Your printer" > Administration Dropdown > Continue on pre-existing settings > Uncheck "Share this Printer"

Comment: But, I WANT to share the printer, it's a network printer after all.  @PJ Sing answer works.