# Disable ubuntu 18.04 printer discovery and printing over wireless network

Tags: 18.04, printing

I want to *disable printer discovery and printing over a wifi network*.

I  have tried:

edit `/etc/cups/cups-browsed.conf` to have

```
BrowseRemoteProtocols none

BrowseDeny
```

restart CUPS from Terminal:

```
service cups restart
```

**It didn't work for ubuntu 18.04**

Comment: Does this link jaelp? https://askubuntu.com/questions/973599/how-do-i-disable-network-printer-discovery-in-ubuntu-17-10

Comment: No, It takes to somewhere else

Comment: You are asking two unrelated questions. As I have the same problem regarding discovery, I'm opening a new question for that. Feel free to create a new question regarding disabling network printing alltogether. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1183730/how-to-disable-network-printer-discovery-in-ubuntu-18-04

Answer (score 0):

Set directive **BrowseProtocols**, this directive apply to both BrowseRemoteProtocols and BrowseLocalProtocols.

Edit `/etc/cups/cups-browsed.conf` and set `BrowseProtocols` to:

```
BrowseProtocols none
```

Then restart `cups-browsed` service:

```
sudo service cups-browsed restart
```