# How to disable network printer discovery in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: networking, 20.04, gnome, printing, 22.04

There are several open questions regarding older Ubuntu versions but none provide a working answer. Here are the steps I tried:

1. I disabled discovery in cups-browsed configuration
2. I disabled the whole service
3. I removed the service
4. I completely disabled avahi.

The last step worked but as I'm using avahi for other network discovery services, I don't want to remove it. Steps 1-3 work in CUPS itself, somehow Gnome is adding the printers, though. So what I'm looking for is the Gnome setting to disable printer discovery.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I disable automatic remote printer installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/345083/how-do-i-disable-automatic-remote-printer-installation)

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question, the only solution I found so far is disabling avahi:

```
sudo systemctl stop avahi-daemon.service
sudo systemctl disable avahi-daemon.service
sudo systemctl stop avahi-daemon.socket
sudo systemctl disable avahi-daemon.socket
```

I would love a better solution of course.

Comment: This disables all network computer discovery, which probably isn't a good idea.

Comment: @Cerin, correct. I’m mentioned this in the question itself.

Comment: @Cerin: could you elaborate on why this is not a good idea? Afaik network computer discovery is a "nice-to-have" at best. I have never found this contributing anything to my Linux experience but cluttering my printer dialogs with dysfunctional network printers on the other end of the network. Which other features do actually rely on Avahi and would break without it?

Comment: @Hinz Avahi is nice for ad-hoc networking of otherwise un-networked devices. e.g. you can plug a Raspberry Pi 4 into the USB-C port of your laptop and it will show up as an Ethernet device. In the absense of a router, both devices will get a random IP and will find each other through mdns (Avahi), so you can just connect via raspberrypi.local. That’s it for me, though. 