# HP Officejet Pro 8720 with Ubuntu 20.04 can't scan from PC

Tags: 20.04, hp, scanner

Ubuntu 20.04LTS --

Printing works fine so I don't want to mess that up since I print more often than I scan.

There are 58 items in usr/share/hplip/ including a folder called scan with 3 items.

Simple scan does not find a scanner.

This would be nice to have but I can work around it by plugging a USB stick in and capturing the scan there.

If anyone has gotten this to work, I'd be interested in the solution.

Thanks!

Comment: This post should not be on here. There is a Stack for a problem of this sort. Here is the link: https://stackapps.com/questions

Comment: I use a multi-function HP 8740 with Ubuntu, and printing and scanning (with simple-scan) work flawlessly. Please Edit your question an let us know how had you originally installed and setup your printer?

Comment: @PJSingh The printer was here before the computer and printing and scanning has been working fine with both MS Windows and Mac OS. The Ubuntu laptop found the network printer during its initial set up without me doing anything. However, I have never been able to scan from the computer. I'm new to Linux but did have a chance to work with UNIX on a RISC 6000 machine in the early 1990's so if my comment isn't helpful, that's why. I'm wondering if I'm just missing part of HPLIP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HP Linux Imaging and Printing site lists [all supported printers](https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/supported_devices/index).

The good news is that "HP OfficeJet Pro 8720 All-in-one Printer" is listed as a supported printer. Additionally the 7th column shows that "Scan to PC" is also supported for this model.

**Install HPLIP (HP Linux Imaging and Printing)**

1. Open a terminal

   (Although most things in Ubuntu can be done using a GUI interface, I'll list the commands because it's more expedient and also easier to document the exact steps).
2. Ensure you have the software repository enabled

   ```
   sudo apt-add-repository universe
   ```

   This will automatically update your repositories, but you can also execute `sudo apt update` to manually update, if needed.
3. Install HPLIP

   ```
   sudo apt install hplip
   ```
4. Optionally, install HPLIP GUI tools

   ```
   sudo apt install hplip-gui
   ```

**Setup your printer (HP OfficeJet Pro 8720 All-in-one Printer)**

1. Get your printer's network name

   On your printer's LCD control panel, drag the gray top-bar down, tap the network icon, and write down the Host Name.

   The network name may be something like "HP_OfficeJet_Pro_8720".

   (You can use your printer's IP address, but I highly recommend setting up your printer using its network name, because IP addresses can change).
2. Setup HPLIP to use your printer

   On your Ubuntu computer, execute the following command.

   Replace "HP_OfficeJet_Pro_8720" with the actual network name of your printer from the previous step.

   *Be sure to add `.local` at the end, as shown!*

   ```
   sudo hp-setup -i HP_OfficeJet_Pro_8720.local
   ```
3. Supply the following information when requested:

   - Please enter a name for this print queue (m=use model name:'psc_2500'*, q=quit) ?:

     ```
     HP_8720_Printer
     ```
   - Does this PPD file appear to be the correct one (y=yes*, n=no, q=quit) ?

     ```
     y
     ```
   - Enter a location description for this printer (q=quit) ?

     *If you want to leave this blank, just press <kbd>Enter</kbd>*
   - Enter additional information or notes for this printer (q=quit) ?

     ```
     HP OfficeJet Pro 8720 Printer
     ```
   - Please enter a name for this fax queue (m=use model name:'psc_2500_fax'*, q=quit) ?

     ```
     HP_8720_Fax
     ```
   - Enter a location description for this printer (q=quit) ?

     *If you want to leave this blank, just press <kbd>Enter</kbd>*
   - Enter additional information or notes for this printer (q=quit) ?

     ```
     HP OfficeJet Pro 8720 Fax
     ```
   - Would you like to perform fax header setup (y=yes*, n=no, q=quit) ?

     ```
     n
     ```
   - Would you like to print a test page (y=yes*, n=no, q=quit) ?

     ```
     n
     ```
4. Make the printer default

   1. In Ubuntu, open System Settings app
   2. Select Printers in the left pane
   3. Click the gear icon next to "HP_8720_Printer"
   4. Check-mark "Use Printer by Default"

**Test Scanning**

1. Launch Simple Scan (aka. "Document Scanner")
2. Wait for "Searching for Scanners" to complete
3. You should see the message "Ready to Scan"
4. Select "HP HP_OfficeJet_Pro_8720" from the drop down
5. Click the <kbd>Scan</kbd> button in the header bar

Comment: It's working just fine! Scanning and printing perfectly. I installed the GUI and see that I can get to all the options that exist in the drivers for MS Windows. Thanks so much for your help! Just one question - in settings there are now multiple printer and fax entries. The default printer is the one with the network name appended but I also have the original entry as well as an entry with the printer appended to the name of the computer. Same with fax entries. What's with that?

Comment: I'm glad it is working. Please click the grey check-mark next to this answer to accept it. Regarding multiple printer and fax entries, this question may have been answered; you can search for answers to this question on AskUbuntu or ask a new question if you don't find an answer. This printer may be shared from different computer(s) on your network, it's possible the printer was previously configured on your computer with a different name, and/or you are seeing it via Bonjour. You can optionally disable Bonjour on your printer (https://askubuntu.com/a/973710/100356).

Comment: Thanks! I didn't notice the check-mark earlier. It's now been clicked. (Did click the up arrow but I haven't been around long enough to vote.) Yeah, forgot about Bonjour... and it is shared from different computers on my network.

Comment: Ubuntu 22 it works for OfficeJet Pro 7720!

Answer (score 0):

@PJ Singh has given a very full answer in the context of HPLIP. My answer is in the context of of fitting your present modern printing setup into a modern scanning method.

Basically: Nothing of HPLIP is needed. This will come as a shock to all the users who advocate its use. However, things have moved on in 2021.

Install [sane-airscan](https://github.com/alexpevzner/sane-airscan) (main page).

Debian packages are [here](https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/pzz/xUbuntu_18.04/amd64/).

I would be very interested in the outputs of `scanimage -L` and `airscan-discover` and whether you can now scan.

Comment: HPLIP seems to be working but I'll definitely keep this note for future reference. Thanks for the information.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my printer problem by turning the printer's power off and then back on.