# After updating from 18.04 to 20.04 HP OfficeJet 8720 produces no output

Tags: 18.04, 20.04, printing, hp

Before updating to 20.04 my HP OfficeJet 8720 worked.
After updating from 18.04 to 20.04 HP OfficeJet 8720 gets

```
lpstat -p
\printer HP-OfficeJet-Pro-8720 now printing HP-OfficeJet-Pro-8720-0.  enabled since Sat 29 May 2021 09:34:09 PM EDT
    Rendering completed
```

but nothing is printed.

Comment: I've successfully used the 8740 with Ubuntu 18.04 and 20.04. The 8740 is very similar to the 8720. See if [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1334736/100356) helps your situation. (The answer was for scanning using the 8720, but of course, it sets up the printer as well).

Answer (score 1):

I unplugged the 8720 and plugged it back in. It then printed.

Comment: What solved it for me was unplugging and then plugging the printer back in. It is now working fine!