# Disable some specific notifications (e.g. "printer added", "tab ... is ready") on GNOME 3

Tags: 17.10, notification, gnome-shell

I recently upgraded to 17.10, and that means that I'm using GNOME for the first time in ages. One new (to me) feature is the notifications area (not sure what it is called) on top, where time and date is displayed.

While sometimes useful, there are many notifications that I would like to suppress, e.g. the "printer added" banner that shows up every 30 minutes or so when I'm connected to a network with a network printer, the "tab ... is ready" from the web browser, etc. Can I disable these notifications on a per-app basis?

I know [there are](https://askubuntu.com/questions/918462/ubuntu-17-04-printer-added-notifications-under-gnome) [specific workarounds](https://askubuntu.com/questions/973599/how-do-i-disable-network-printer-discovery-in-ubuntu-17-10) to reduce the number of notifications from network printers, but I'm asking for a more general solution, if there is any.

[image: Notification area with two “printer added” notifications.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although there are options to change notification settings per app in *Settings* > *Notifications*, it won't help your cause. As you have already mentioned in your question, there are some older questions which deal with the "*printer added*" notification, e.g.

- [Ubuntu 17.04 - 'printer added' notifications under Gnome](https://askubuntu.com/questions/918462/ubuntu-17-04-printer-added-notifications-under-gnome)
- [How do I disable network printer discovery in Ubuntu 17.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/973599/how-do-i-disable-network-printer-discovery-in-ubuntu-17-10)

Finally, those "*X is ready*" notifications are sent by GNOME shell itself, not by the specific application. Possibly the easiest way to disable those by using some [GNOME shell extensions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75530/how-do-i-install-and-manage-gnome-shell-extensions), e.g.

1. ['Window Is Ready' Notification Remover](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1007/window-is-ready-notification-remover/)
2. [NoAnnoyance](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1236/noannoyance/) (Removes the 'Windows is ready' notification and also puts the window into focus)
3. [Focus my window](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1005/focus-my-window/) (Removes the 'Windows is ready' notification and also puts the window into focus)

<sub>**NOTE:** Some extensions may not be compatible with your GNOME shell version.</sub>