# Ubuntu 20.04 disable notifications at startup

Tags: printing, 20.04, notification

Is there a way to disable lock screen notifications at startup?
Reason I am asking is that every time I boot up my laptop, I get the "printer added" notification, and it gets incredibly annoying. Disabling printer notifications and lock screen notifications does NOT work (it only works *after* login, which defeats the purpose)

I have tried to see if the printer added notification could be fixed as a bug, but the bug report has since been ignored...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove 'printer added' notifications from GNOME 3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/918462/remove-printer-added-notifications-from-gnome-3) should be the same in 20.04

Comment: Go to Settings->Privacy->Screen Lock -> Disable Show Notifications on Lock Screen

Comment: I agree with @kannzzmm2

Comment: @kannzzmm2 Like I said, disabling notifications in settings does not work. The notification settings are completely ignored until I login for the first time.

Comment: @User24601 not sure if that really solve the problem. I would honestly prefer to try to get this bug fixed rather than simply hide the notification, but I would like to know how to make all lock screen notifications be disabled at startup (disabling via settings _does not work_)